# Drop shadow on one layer affecting another layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am working on Photoshop, I added a drop shadow on two different layers, the drop shadow have a different color on each layer, where these two layers  meet they form a dark blackish shadow, how can I avoid this, in such a way that the shadow of each layer has not effect on the shadow of the other layer.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmVmx.png]

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Be more specific. "Not having effect" on eachother is not specific at all considering the layers are overlapping and some effect is to be expected due to that, what exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I do not want the blackish shadow where the brown and blue layer meet.

Comment: You didn't understand. You should specify on these StackExchange websites as to what you **want**, not what you don't want. E.g. I guess you also don't want empty space there. The answer below assumes the most probable request of shadows just being separated, but no point replying when it could have been something else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put each layer in its own layer group
2. Create a mask for each group (not the layer)

[image]

3. Draw each mask so the dropshadows do not overlap

[image]

[image]

[image]